# Exclude files while removing folders recursively

Tags: php, recursion, bitbucket, rmdir

I'm working on public project - which replaces FTP deployment method fully with GIT for PHP based projects. You place 1 file - deploy php in you website's root directory. That's all. When you push something into Bitbucket git repo, this script fetches zip and replaces all website files with zip contents

What I want to do is,

1. to clear the folder (root in my case) where script located EXCLUDING this script and .htaccess
2. Then download zip
3. unzip into $dest
4. Copy $dest's contents into root
5. Remove dest and all it's contents

In other words, it must replace whole root with new zip's contents excluding script itself and few other files (which listed in $exc array). That's all. The problem is, my function `rmdir_recursively` doesn't exlude files, removes all including script. What am I missing?

What other optimizations can you suggest for script?

Thx in advance.

```
<?php

// Set these dependant on your BB credentials    
$username = '';
$password = '';

// your Bitbucket repo name
$reponame = "";

// extract to
$dest = "./"; // leave ./ for relative destination


//Exclusion list
$exc = array("deploy.php", ".htaccess");

// Grab the data from BB's POST service and decode
$json = stripslashes($_POST['payload']);
$data = json_decode($json);

// set higher script timeout (for large repo's or slow servers)
set_time_limit(5000);

// Set some parameters to fetch the correct files
$uri = $data->repository->absolute_url;
$node = $data->commits[0]->node;
$files = $data->commits[0]->files;

//Clear Root 
rmdir_recursively(".");

// download the repo zip file
$fp = fopen("tip.zip", 'w');

$ch = curl_init("https://bitbucket.org/$username/$reponame/get/$node.zip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

// unzip
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('tip.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('./');
    $zip->close();
} else {
    die('ZIP not supported on this server!');
}

// function to delete all files in a directory recursively
function rmdir_recursively($dir) {
    global $exc;
    if(in_array($dir,$exc)) return false;
    if (!is_dir($dir) || is_link($dir)) return unlink($dir); 
        foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) { 
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue; 
            if (!rmdir_recursively($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) { 
                chmod($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, 0777); 
                if (!rmdir_recursively($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) return false; 
            }; 
        } 
        return rmdir($dir); 
}

// function to recursively copy the files
function copy_recursively($src, $dest) {
    if (is_dir($src)) {
        if ($dest != "./")
            rmdir_recursively($dest);
        @mkdir($dest);
        $files = scandir($src);
        foreach ($files as $file)
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                copy_recursively("$src/$file", "$dest/$file");
    }
    else if (file_exists($src))
        copy($src, $dest);
    rmdir_recursively($src);
}

// start copying the files from extracted repo and delete the old directory recursively
copy_recursively("$username-$reponame-$node", $dest);

// delete the repo zip file
unlink("tip.zip");
?>
```

Comment: *"What other optimizations can you suggest for script?"* - Use file-system abstraction with `DirectoryIterator` and it's recursive pendant. Provide a `FilterIterator` to exclude your files.

Comment: @hakre can you please apply your suggestion on code?

Comment: @hakre It's public project, I'm trying to make life easy for git and php lovers, that's why you're not helping only me but community

Comment: Please use the search. I've given some examples already on site (as did others) and there should be off-site examples for those as well.

Comment: Also take a look into existing projects, e.g. there is `Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder`. Also as you already unpack into ´$dest` you could than use that directory to copy over your permanent files in there and then move the whole around to it's final destination (or change the symlink).

Comment: Does changing the excluded path to "./deploy.php" work? Although I do agree with hakre; using string manipulation is unnecessary.

Comment: And finally: Just install git on the server side. It works, you can create good deployment setups straight away, no need to fetch duplicate files and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

// set higher script timeout (for large repo's or slow servers)
$timeLimit = 5000;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$mode = intval(isset($_POST['payload']));

if (isset($_GET['commit']))
    $mode = 2;

$force = isset($_GET['force']);
$owner = (isset($owner)) ? $owner : $username; // if user is owner
$repo = $reponame;
$response = "";

if ($mode == 0) { // manual deploy

    function callback($url, $chunk) {
        global $response;
        $response .= $chunk;
        return strlen($chunk);
    }

    ;

    $ch = curl_init("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/$owner/$repo/changesets?limit=1");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'callback');
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $changesets = json_decode($response, true);
    $node = $changesets['changesets'][0]['node'];
    $raw_node = $changesets['changesets'][0]['raw_node'];
} else if ($mode == 1) { // auto deploy
    $json = stripslashes($_POST['payload']);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    // Set some parameters to fetch the correct files
    $uri = $data->repository->absolute_url;
    $node = $data->commits[0]->node;
    echo $node;
    $files = $data->commits[0]->files;
} else if ($mode == 2) { // deploy with hash code
    $node = $_GET['commit'];
    $node = substr($node, 0, 12);
    echo 'commit: ' . $node . "\n";
}
// Check last commit hash

if (isset($_GET['updated'])) {
    echo "\n<br>Bitbucket Deploy Updated<br>\n";
}

set_time_limit($timeLimit);

// Grab the data from BB's POST service and decode
// Clear Root
// download the repo zip file

if (!$force && file_exists('lastcommit.hash')) {
    $lastcommit = file_get_contents('lastcommit.hash');
    if ($lastcommit == $node)
        die('Project is already up to date');
}

file_put_contents('lastcommit.hash', $node);


$fp = fopen("tip.zip", 'w');

$ch = curl_init("https://bitbucket.org/$owner/$reponame/get/$node.zip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$exc["files"][] = realpath("tip.zip");

$tipsize = filesize("tip.zip");

if ($tipsize < 50) {
    die("Commit not found");
}

if ($autoUpdate)
    updateDeploy();

//var_dump($exc);
//die();


RemoveDir(realpath($dest), true, $exc);


// unzip
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('tip.zip');
if ($res !== TRUE) {
    die('ZIP not supported on this server!');
}

$zip->extractTo("$dest/");
$zip->close();

copy_recursively("$owner-$reponame-$node", $dest);

RemoveDir(realpath("$owner-$reponame-$node"), false);
@rmdir("$owner-$reponame-$node");
// Delete the repo zip file
unlink("tip.zip");

// function to delete all files in a directory recursively

function updateDeploy() {
    global $force;
    global $dest;
    global $mode;
    $updated = isset($_GET['updated']);
    //var_dump($_GET);
    if ($updated)
        return true;

    $response = "";

    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/codearts/bitbucket-deploy/changesets?limit=1");

    $changesets = json_decode($response, true);
    $node = $changesets['changesets'][0]['node'];
    $raw_node = $changesets['changesets'][0]['raw_node'];

    $lastcommit = file_get_contents('data.hash');
    if (file_exists('data.hash')) {    //   if (!$force && file_exists('data.hash')) {
        $lastcommit = file_get_contents('data.hash');
        if ($lastcommit == $node)
            return;
    }
    file_put_contents('data.hash', $node);
    $deployLink = "https://bitbucket.org/codearts/bitbucket-deploy/get/$node.zip";
    $deploy = file_get_contents($deployLink);

    $f = fopen("deploy.zip", "w");
    fwrite($f, $deploy);
    fclose($f);
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open('deploy.zip');
    if ($res !== TRUE) {
        die('ZIP not supported on this server!');
    }
    $zip->extractTo("$dest/");
    $zip->close();
    unlink('deploy.php');
    copy("codearts-bitbucket-deploy-$node/deploy.php", 'deploy.php');
    //unlink("codearts-bitbucket-deploy-$node/deploy.php");
    RemoveDir(realpath("codearts-bitbucket-deploy-$node"), false);
    @rmdir(realpath("codearts-bitbucket-deploy-$node"));

    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/deploy.php?updated" . (($force) ? '&force' : '');

    header("Location:" . $url);
    die();

//    if($mode != 1) echo "\n<br>Bitbucket Deploy Updated<br>\n";
}

// Deleting with exclude list


function checkExcluding($path, $excludinglist) {
    if (!isset($excludinglist["files"]))
        return false;
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        return in_array($path, $excludinglist["files"]);
    }
    else
        return in_array($path, $excludinglist["dirs"]);
}

function RemoveDir($dir, $exclude = false, $excludelist = array()) {
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    //  var_dump($files);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($exclude && checkExcluding($file->getRealPath(), $excludelist)) {
            //  echo 'Excluding: ' . $file->getRealPath() . '<br>';
            continue;
        }

        if ($file->isDir()) {
            @rmdir($file->getRealPath());
            //echo 'DIR: ' . $file->getRealPath() . '<br>';
        } else {
            @unlink($file->getRealPath());
            //echo 'FILE: ' . $file->getRealPath() . '<br>';
        }
    }
    if (file_exists($dir))
        @rmdir($dir);
}

function copy_recursively($src, $dest) {
    //var_dump($src);
    global $exc;
    $excludeDirsNames = array();
    $excludeFileNames = $exc["files"];
    //     var_dump(  $excludeFileNames  );

    if (is_dir('' . $src)) {
        //  var_dump($src);
        // if ($dest != "./")
        //   rmdir_recursively($dest);
        @mkdir($dest);
        $files = scandir($src);



        // var_dump( $excludeFileNames );

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (!in_array($file, $excludeDirsNames)) {

                if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                    copy_recursively("$src/$file", "$dest/$file");
            }
        }
    }
    else if (file_exists($src)) {

        $filename = $src;
        $filename = end(explode("/", $src));
        //$filename = $filename[count( $filename)-2];
        if (!in_array($filename, $excludeFileNames)) {
            //var_dump($filename);
            // var_dump(in_array( $filename, $excludeDirsNames));
            copy($src, $dest);
        }
    }
    //  rmdir_recursively($src);
}

if ($mode != 1)
    echo '<br>Done';
?>
```